# linked list is not removing/adding first heads

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

I am creating a program that adds/removes a head when it is a match, however it is not working. Is there anything wrong with these two functions? I have more linked list code but these are the two I am using in my program.

They are supposed to work similar to a  push/pop function of a stack

```
linkedList* createLinkedList()
{
    linkedList* list;
    list = malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
    list->size = 0;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    return list;
}
void insertStart(linkedList* list, void* inData)
{
    listNode* node;
    node = (listNode*)malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    node->data = inData;
    list->size++;
    if (list->head == NULL)
    { 
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
        node->next = NULL;
        node->prev = NULL;
    }
    else
    { 
    
        list->head->prev = node;
        node->next = list->head;
        node->prev = NULL;
        list->head = node;
    }
}

void* removeStart(linkedList* list)
{
    listNode* removed = NULL;
   /* void* outData = NULL;*/
 
        removed = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        list->head->prev = NULL;
        list->size -= 1;
       /* outData = removed->data;
        free(removed);*/
   
    return removed;
}
```

Comment: Just a side-note, unless you have a specific need for the `size` member, as you add more functionality to your list , a `size` member can be cumbersome to maintain -- and of limited usefulness. (other than answering "How many nodes to do I have?" or if you are limiting the number of nodes)  Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Although `insertStart` will function correctly, it can be considerably simplified:

```
void insertStart(linkedList* list, void* inData)
{
    listNode* node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    node->data = inData;
    node->next = list->head;
    node->prev = NULL;
    if (list->head)
        list->head->prev = node;
    else
        list->tail = node;
    list->head = node;
    list->size++;
}
```

However, the real problem is `removeStart`. It has several gaping flaws:

1. It doesn't manage the `tail` pointer whatsoever.
2. It assumes the list is non-empty.
3. Incorrect result returned. (you want to return the data member; not the node pointer)

The former of those will completely break everything that requires a properly managed tail pointer; the second will invoke *undefined* behavior if an empty list. The final item is just  oversight. All of them can be addressed in fewer than a twenty lines of code:

```
void* removeStart(linkedList* list)
{
    void *data = NULL;

    if (list->head)
    {
        listNode* removed = list->head;
        list->head = removed->next;
        if (list->head)
            list->head->prev = NULL;
        else
            list->tail = NULL;
        data = removed->data;
        free(removed);
        --list->size;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `insertStart` contains a duplicated code. Also to prevent undefined behavior it should check whether a memory for a new node was successfully allocated.

The function can be declared and defined the following way.

```
int insertStart(linkedL ist *list, void* inData )
{
    listNode *node = malloc( sizeof( listNode ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        node->data = inData;
        node->next = list->head;
        node->prev = NULL;

        if ( list->head == NULL )
        {
            list->tail = node;
        }
        else
        {
            list->head->prev = node;
        }

        list->head = node;
        ++list->size;
    }

    return success;
}
```

The main problem with the function `emoveStart` is that it does not check whether the list is empty. Also it does not update the node pointed to by the pointer `tail` when the list contains one node.

The functipon can be defined the following way

```
void *  removeStart( linkedList *list )
{
    void *data = NULL;

    if ( list->head != NULL )
    {
        listNode *removed = list->head;
        data = removed->data;

        list->head = list->head->next;

        if ( list->head == NULL )
        {
            list->tail = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            list->prev = NULL;
        }

        free( removed );
        --list->size;
    }

    return data;
}
```